# CSS Layout with Separate Fixed, Scrollable Content Regions

Tags: css, css-position, scrollable

Struggling to achieve my desired functionality in my CSS layout.

Based on this basic structure https://jsfiddle.net/606ep8g7/6/. I'm trying to get the following pieces to work together:

```
<body>
    <div id="A">
        <div id="A1">
        </div>
        <div id="A2">
        </div>
        <div id="A3">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="dragbar"></div>
    <div id="B">
    </div>
</body>
```

- 2 containers: **#A** and **#B** with a div to resize them relative to each other.
- **#A** is fixed (no scrolling) and contains 3 divs: **#A1** which is a fixed logo, **#A2** which is a nav bar, and **#A3** which is a container for a jstree list.

**#A1** is fixed height, while **#A2** wraps its content which must always be visible. This works all right.

I'm trying to get **#A3** to have auto scroll bars inside the fixed **#A** element, while at the same time achieving scroll bars on **#B** when the content is pushing outside the window, and I can't seem to get these to work.

I just can't find the right combination to get all of these working properly. If I make **#A3** position:absolute, I can get scroll bars but it's no longer relative to the dynamic adjustment of **#A2**. But when relative, **#A3** doesn't expand to the bottom of the window nor auto place scrollbars on content overflow. I can't fix the height of the DIV because it's dynamically populated AND needs to adjust with **#A2**. Any ideas?

Comment: did you try setting #A3's height to 100%

Comment: That sets #A3s height to 100% of the parent height, I believe, and not the remaining space of the parent under #A1 and #A2. If you try it in the fiddle, #A3 scrolls well below the visible window but you cannot see the bottom content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`display:flex` and `flex:1` + `overflow` on the `div` to be scrollable might be a solution: https://jsfiddle.net/606ep8g7/7/

Comment: This is excellent. I couldn't figure out how to get flexbox working for this situation; but it's such a simple modification! Thank you! 
Is there any way to contain the #B x-scrollbar within it's own container, and not across the entire browser?

Comment: @stacked well , just use the same method :) https://jsfiddle.net/GCyrillus/606ep8g7/10/ and drop position not flexible enough for this

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using javascript to dynamically change the width, you can do the same with the height.

```
$('#A3').css('height', $('#A').outerHeight() - $('#A1').outerHeight() - $('#A2').outerHeight())
```

I set the initial height of #A3 based on the heights of the other two elements using javascript.  Similarly, the height of #A3 is changed on mousemove.  This isn't a pure CSS solution but since you're manipulating the width using JS, there's no reason not to do the same with the height.

http://jsfiddle.net/3bdenypq/2/

Comment: It would be a simple issue if #A2 did not need to keep contents inline and wrapped. Even without relying on the flaky `calc` function, I could set #A3 as absolute and just specify the fixed `top` and `bottom` positions and be good to go. But in this situation (based on the necessary properties of #A2), it's not such a simple solution. Thanks for the thought, though.

Comment: actually this still doesn't work because of the is pusihing it lower than needed again.100%

Comment: I modified my solution using JS.  please see fiddle.

Comment: I'm not sure that the fiddle is updated. I was about to give up and look into a JS solution, so thank you for that code above. The flexbox solution by GCyrillus below is a pure CSS solution that works in modern browsers, but your JS solution works just as well.

Comment: looks like i forgot to hit update.  it's should be working now.  sorry i wasn't able to provide something purely CSS.  i think CSS will be more flexible in the future once they start allowing variables.

Comment: Works good. Just need to update the link in your post to the new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3bdenypq/2/ Thanks again, and agreed on the CSS; it's come a long way, but still has a long way to go, unfortunately.